# RegExp Find and Replace ignoring part matches

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace, regexp-like

I have a string formatted like:

```
'(val$1,val$1,val$1,val$2,val$3,val$4,val$5,val$6,val$7,val$8,val$9,val$10,val$11,val$12)'
```

and what I am trying to do is replace `val$1` with some text e.g. `XYZ`

Matching on just `val$1` produces:

```
'(XYZ,XYZ,XYZ,val$2,val$3,val$4,val$5,val$6,val$7,val$8,val$9,XYZ0,XYZ1,XYZ2)'
```

If anyone fancies giving me a hand, I would love to know what reg exp would ignore the ones at the end so the resulting string would look like:

```
'(XYZ,XYZ,XYZ,val$2,val$3,val$4,val$5,val$6,val$7,val$8,val$9,val$10,val$11,val$12)'
```

Comment: Something like `\bval\$1\b` https://regex101.com/r/7bO9ar/1/

Comment: Thanks for that. Outside of Oracle, that is looking good by I am using their REGEXP_REPLACE and \b is not supported. Is there another way around this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. You should add those relevant tags to the question to reach the correct *audience* :)

Comment: ok, cheers (and tags added)

Comment: If word boundaries aren't supported, you can try `val\$1(,|\))` This only matches substrings with `,` or `)` after `val$1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an extra digit by `\D` to the pattern for `regexp_replace`

```
select regexp_replace('(val$1,val$1,val$1,val$2,val$3,val$4,val$5,val$6,val$7,val$8,val$9,
                        val$10,val$11,val$12)','\val\$1(\D)','XYZ\1') as "Result"
  from dual;

Result
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(XYZ,XYZ,XYZ,val$2,val$3,val$4,val$5,val$6,val$7,val$8,val$9,val$10,val$11,val$12)
```

Comment: @dunkyduncs and Barbaros. This puts an extra comma at the end if there's a `val$1` at the end , i.e just before `)`.  Try `REGEXP_REPLACE(string, ','\val\$1(\D)','XYZ\1')` instead

Comment: ..or even better `[^0-9a-zA-Z]` instead of `\D`

Comment: @KaushikNayak yes, your solution is more generalized and better, thanks.Depending on mine, I preferred the first one.

Comment: Thanks. What do the the brackets do in this instance \val\$1([^0-9a-zA-Z])

Comment: @dunkyduncs welcome, yes this works, too. But I think no need to include all these pattern elements verbosely.

Comment: `SELECT regexp_replace( '(val$1,val$1,val$1,val$2,P0_COY,val$3,val$4,P0_COY2,val$5,P0_COY_2,val$6,val$7,val$8,val$9,val$10,val$11,val$12)' , '\P0_COY(\D)' , '''XYZ''\1' , 1, 0, 'i') as tester FROM dual;` `(val$1,val$1,val$1,val$2,'XYZ',val$3,val$4,P0_COY2,val$5,'XYZ'_2,val$6,val$7,val$8,val$9,val$10,val$11,val$12)` How can I deal with the _ character so that the result set look like: `(val$1,val$1,val$1,val$2,'XYZ',val$3,val$4,P0_COY2,val$5,P0_COY_2,val$6,val$7,val$8,val$9,val$10,val$11,val$12)`

Comment: Think I have solved it: ([^0-9a-z_]) in place of (\D)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need regular expressions for that? Looks like a simple task for the good, old `REPLACE` function. If there's a lot of data you have to deal with, regex will probably be way slower.

```
SQL> select replace('(val$1,val$1,val$1,val$2,val$3,val$4,val$5,val$6,val$7,val$8,val$9,val$10,val$11,val$12)',
  2                 'val$1,', 'xyz,') result
  3  from dual;

RESULT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(xyz,xyz,xyz,val$2,val$3,val$4,val$5,val$6,val$7,val$8,val$9,val$10,val$11,val$12)

SQL>
```

Comment: Not the desired result set, so yes, a reg exp is needed. See above for the desired output. Cheers, Duncs

Comment: Ah! Sorry, didn't notice the end of the string. Anyway, REPLACE still does the job. I modified code I previously posted, have a look.

Comment: Which *minor issue* is it?

Answer (score 0):

You could also search for `"val$1"` where followed by a comma or a closing paren (if it happens to be at the end of the string).

```
'val\$1(,|\\)', 'XYZ\1'
```